# Постепенная подгрузка гиф изображения

Tags: javascript, jquery

Как сделать так, чтобы gif-файл сначала был статичным, после того как гиф загрузилась, включается воспроизведение само по себе?

Answer (score 1):

Делаем 2 картинки. Первая - первый кадр с гифки, его вставляем прямо в код. Гифку грузим в скрытый тег и после загрузки меняем первую картинку на гифку.